# PHP Получить переменную из другого файла, не выполняя прочих функций

Tags: php, сессия, require

В одном файле, скажем 1.php формируется переменная, номер заказа:

```
        $year = date('Y');
        core::$db->change("INSERT INTO `orders` SET `year`='$year', `info`='{FORMING}'");
        $oid = core::$db->lastid;
        $number = $oid . '-' . $year;
```

И нужно из него вытянуть этот сформированный номер в файл 2.php, для отправки этого номера на почту менеджеру и клиенту, но подключая include и require, выполняются другие функции - в моем случае стили заменяются. Можно ли вытянуть только эту переменную и ничего более?
Пробовала через сессию, но получилось, что переменная создавалась дважды, с разными номерами внутри

Comment: Передать с помощью GET параметров?

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто. Для того, чтобы выполнить только одно действие, не выполняя прочих, надо, чтобы файл выполнял только одно действие.

Файл "1.php" (надеюсь, в реальности он называется как-то осмысленно) должен делать только то, что написано здесь.

И так же нам будет нужно два других файла, которые вызывают его через include: старый файл "1.php", и новый.

Либо - если все должно происходить одновременно, и генерация номера, и отправка его на емейл - то отправку сообщения менеджеру надо вызывать через include после выполнения данного кода.

В более продвинутом варианте можно будет изучить функции и классы, которые также позволяют выполнять отдельные действия по запросу.

Comment: Это первое, что я так же испробовала: создала number_order.php с генерацией этого номера,  но опять же, инклюдом этот код срабатывал формируя номер для 1.php ( и да, это условные названия :) ), а затем формировал новый номер в 2.php

Comment: значит надо инклюдить 2.php в 1.php. А заодно описать в вопросе все тонкости взаимоотношений этих трех файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Redis не подойдёт? Да, я понимаю, что в данном случае это слегка оверкилл, но тем не менее это решит поставленную задачу.

Если такая ситуация повторяется регулярно, можно заюзать AMQP решение, например, RabbitMQ.